# Speed reduction in ode45 when i pass parameters from workspace

Tags: matlab, global-variables, ode

I'm trying to simulate a system with **ode45**.

I have tried two strategy which they have very different run times.

At first I declare necessary variables and assign it's values inside the function solved by **ode** :

```
   function dy = Fun2_004(t,y,frequency)
    dy=zeros(11,1)
    %Initialization of variables
    K_t=.559;
    f_Theta=.002;
    J=5e-7;
    K_Theta=9.45e-4;
    .
    .
    .
    %equations
    dy=...
end

[T2,Y2] = ode45(@(t,y)Fun2_004(t,y,Omega_Hertz),[0 Time],Inits,options);
```

> This code take 0.5 seconds to execute.

I want to use this code in an optimization process so I pass it's variables as arguments of this function :

```
function dy = Fun2_004_PSO(t,y,frequency,InputVars)
    dy=zeros(11,1)
    %Initialization of variables
    K_t=InputVars(1);
    f_Theta=InputVars(2);
    J=InputVars(3);
    K_Theta=InputVars(4);
    .
    .
    .
    %equations
    dy=...
end`

   [T2,Y2] = ode45(@(t,y)Fun2_004_PSO(t,y,Omega_Hertz,InputVars),[0 Time],Inits,options);
```

> This code take 40 second to execute!!!

I tried global variables, **codegen** and **persistent** variables but it has no considerable effect.

Does any body exactly knows source and solution of this problem?

> > [Edited]
> >     here i brought a part of code with further details

```
>`function [dy] = Fun2_EHSV_004_PSO(t,y,Omega,InputVars)
dy = zeros(7,1);
K_t=InputVars(9);%K_t=.559;
K_T=InputVars(11);%K_T=10.8;
L_f=InputVars(1);%L_f=9e-3;
L_s=InputVars(2);%L_s=30e-3;
d_f=InputVars(3);%d_f=0.5e-3;
d_5=InputVars(5);%d_5=0.6e-3;
d_s=InputVars(4);%d_s=4.6e-3;
w=InputVars(8);%w=.01446;
c=InputVars(6);%c=2e-6;
f_s=InputVars(7);%f_s=3.035;
K_s=InputVars(10);%K_s=900;
%%
f_Theta=.002;
J=5e-7;
K_Theta=9.45e-4;
K_FB=.04;
x_i=30e-6;
R_s=5000;
K_Lf=5e6;
Rhuo=867;
B=1.5e9;
V_0=2e-6;
V_3=5e-6;
m_s=0.02;
P_s=250e5;
P_T=0;
%
A_0=0.25*pi*(5e-4)^2;
A_s=0.25*pi*d_s^2;
A_5=0.25*pi*d_5^2;
C_d=0.661;
C_c=1e1;
%
i_e = .01*sind(Omega*t);
%%
T=K_t*i_e+K_Theta*y(1);
F_s=K_s*(L_s*y(1)+y(6));
x_f=L_f*y(1);
C_12=C_d*A_0*sqrt(2/Rhuo);
C_34=C_d*pi*d_f*sqrt(2/Rhuo);
C_5=C_d*A_5*sqrt(2/Rhuo);
%%
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = (1/J)*(T-K_T*y(1)-f_Theta*y(2));
dy(3) = (C_12*sqrt(P_s-y(3))-C_34*(x_i+x_f)*sqrt(y(3)-y(5))+A_s*y(7))/((V_0-  A_s*y(6))/B);
dy(4) = (C_12*sqrt(P_s-y(4))-C_34*(x_i-x_f)*sqrt(y(4)-y(5))- A_s*y(7))/((V_0+A_s*y(6))/B);
dy(5) = (C_34*(x_i+x_f)*sqrt(y(3)-y(5))+C_34*(x_i-x_f)*sqrt(y(4)-y(5))-            C_5*sqrt(y(5)-P_T))/(V_3/B);
dy(6) = y(7);   F_j=0;%F_s=0;
dy(7) = (A_s*(y(4)-y(3))-f_s*y(7)-F_j-F_s)/m_s;`



[T2,Y2] = ode45(@(t,y)Fun2_test(t,y,Omega,In),[0 .37],[0 0 100e5 100e5   100e5 0 0]);
```

Comment: Please provide the full code and your Matlab Version.

Comment: full code has brought in edited text

Comment: when running your code in R2015a, there is no speed difference between the two versions, so this seems to be fixed now.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply. do you know what is the source of problem?should i get 2015 version ?

Comment: No, I don't know the source. Yes, upgrading might help. You could contact the Mathworks support about that.

Comment: I just tested this in R2013b and I cannot replicate the issue. The run times are identical and both well under 0.5 seconds. You should specify exactly how you're performing the timing and exactly what code you're running. My guess is that you have some variable.value that is different between the two versions. Compare them closely. Also check your `options`.

Comment: thank you all for your useful comments. I tried 2015a. in this version, a warning is displayed and said it may be because of variable precisions. when i  tightened the tolerance, problem has solved.